# Asp.net Ajax Tookit AutoCompleteExtender stops working in update panel after partial postback

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I have an update panel with some text entry boxes, a clear button and a save button.  Under the boxes I have a repeater that holds database entries.  When a user enters data in the textboxes and clicks the Save, a database row is created and the repeater rebinds and shows the new dataset.  There are buttons on each repeater row for "Delete" and "Edit".  When the Edit button is clicked on a row, the data from that row is populated back into the text boxes.  When I do that, the autocomplete extenders stop working.  I have a button that simply clears the textboxes.  If I click that button and clear the textboxes, the autocomplete starts working again.  Even if I remove all code from that "Edit" button in the repeater command and don't have it populate the text boxes from the row clicked, the autocomplete stops working.  Something is happening on the item command for the repeater row that is turning off the autocomplete.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had some javascript functions running from the code behind on page load.  Moving that from the server side page load to the javascript pageLoad() function fixed the issue